# event preventDefault apparently not working properly in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

For some odd reason `event.PrventDefault` is not working properly in meteor events.

I try this on jsFiddle and it works as expected (The enter doesn't go to the new line). 
Here is a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/6abCN/)

However, similar code in meteor events is not working, the enter is registering a break in the textarea.

```
'keyup #add_comment_content' : function(event) {

    if (event.keyCode == 13) { // When the enter key is pressed 
        event.preventDefault();
        //var content = $(this).val();
        //var id = $(this).parent().find('comment_content_id').val();
        //console.log(content);
        //console.log(id);
        console.log("Hey");
    }
}
```

Comment: To me, your result sounds logical. On the `keyup` event (after the key has been pressed), the character (the newline) has been written to the textarea. Don't know what one could expect from `event.preventDefault()` after that. Use the `keydown` event instead if you want to avoid writing the character to the textarea.

Comment: Try wrapping it all in a form tag and watch the submit event instead (do your event.preventDefault in there). Watching for keyCode 13 is pretty hacky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by using the `keypress` event instead of the `keyup` event. I tried this because the docs mentioned:

> keypress is most useful for catching typing in text fields, while keydown and keyup can be used for arrow keys or modifier keys.